# Restore Content Type Switcher in Custom List Form

Tags: custom-form

I'm trying to restore the Content Type pop-up menu selector that is part of the default Edit Form for a custom list. In SPD 2013 you can create a new form for a list from the Forms section. In the next dialoguer you can select which content type you want to use. SPD creates a new page with all the relevant columns for that content type. It doesn't however create a content type pop-up that allows you to switch to other content types.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? I thought it might be creating a custom page layout but that is missing even more content.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Content Type pop-up selector/switcher]
[image: Create New From]
[image: Specify Content Type]

Answer (score 0):

You can only select Content Types which are assigned to the List you want to create the NewForm for.

What exactly do you want to have? A Form which fills a List with Products, when the Products Content Type is selected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to reduce the amount of fields per form. Say I have 10 columns 5 assigned to content type a five to b. Using the default edit form there's a content type pop-up that lets me switch between "a" and "b". If I create a new form [so I can add some javascript, change the layout, add some images, etc.] and choose content type "a" as per above images, the content type pop-up is no longer there.